# Как импортировать метод closeTo?

Tags: java, junit, импорт

```
package com.company;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class TriangleTest {
    @Test
    public void areaTriangle(){
        Triangle.Point a = new Triangle.Point(0, 0);
        Triangle.Point b = new Triangle.Point(0, 2);
        Triangle.Point c = new Triangle.Point(2, 0);
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle(a, b, c);
        double result = triangle.area();
        double expected = 2D;
        assertThat(result, closeTo(expected),0.1);
        /**
         ????????????????????????????????
         */
    }
}
```

`closeTo` выделяется красным цветом. Как импортировать его или метод? Не могу сделать тест.

Comment: а что это вообще за `closeTo`?

Answer (score 4):

Возможно имеется ввиду метод [`Matchers.closeTo`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#closeTo(double,%20double)) из hamcrest. Если да, то этот метод принимает два аргумента (значение и погрешность) и в коде неправильно расставлены скобки:

```
 assertThat(result, closeTo(expected, 0.1));
```

Импорт выглядит так:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.closeTo;
```

Для доступности добавьте [hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) в зависимости/библиотеки.